# igraph - get all edges which form a path between two vertex - Is there a better solution?

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I have a graph with different trails between checkpoints (for trailrunning). 
An example could look like this.

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

example_data = data.frame(start = c("D_2", "A_2", "A_2", "E_2", "G_2", "H_2", "G_2", "A_2", "B_2", "C_2", "C_2", "D_2"), 
                             end = c("D_1", "A_1", "B_1", "E_1", "G_1", "H_1", "F_1", "B_1", "A_1", "C_1", "C_1", "A_1"), 
                             length = rnorm(12, 100, 10),
                             difficulty = c("soft", "soft", "medium", "medium", "soft", "soft", "soft", "soft", "soft", "soft", "medium", "hard"),
                             trail = c(paste0("trail_", 1:11), "Fake_pist"), 
                             stringsAsFactors = F)

# relable connected end and start section points (sometimes the end of a trail is so close to the start of the next that they are seen as one point)
example_data$start[which(example_data$start %in%  c("D_1", "A_2"))] = "A_2_D_1"
example_data$end[which(example_data$end %in%  c("D_1", "A_2"))] = "A_2_D_1"

example_graph = graph_from_data_frame(example_data, directed = T)
```

There can be different trails or trail-combinations to get from one checkpoint to another, the graph is directional since running the trail is allowed only in one direction.

```
p <- ggraph(example_graph) + 
  geom_edge_fan(aes(color = as.factor(difficulty), 
                    start_cap = label_rect(node1.name), 
                    end_cap = label_rect(node2.name),
                    label = trail), arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(3, 'mm')),
                angle_calc = 'along') + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) + 
  ggtitle('An example') +
  scale_edge_colour_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green"))
p
```

For a trailrunner i want to find out which possible ways he could take from a startingpoint to an endpoint and i want to know the length, the difficulty and so on of this trails. 
For example if a runner starts at D_2 and wants to get to B_1 he has to take trail_1 first to reach A_2_D_1 and than can pick between trail_8 and trail_3 to reach B_1.
The possible pathways therefore are:
D_2 -> A_2_D_1 -> B_1 (in vertix form)
trail_1 -> trail_8 or trail_1 -> trail_3 (in edge form)

I am interessted in the edge form because the information i need is stored with the edges. 
I couldn't find a premade function to deliver the desired results, so i created my own one, but i think its a rather bad solution, so i would be very glad if you could suggest some improvements or even a premade function if there is one.

The function to be improved:

```
# get all simple path (== desired results but in Vertix-form )
l = all_simple_paths(example_graph, from = "D_2", to = "B_1", mode = "out")
l

l2 = all_simple_paths(example_graph, from = "D_2", to = "A_1", mode = "out")
l2



my_get_edges = function(temp_vertix, temp_graph)
{
  # convert graph to data.frame
  temp_graph_df = igraph::as_data_frame(temp_graph, what="edges")

  # If the overall path consists of more than just 1 trail.
  temp_vertix = names(temp_vertix)
  if(length(temp_vertix) > 2)
  {
    # create matrix with each row beeing start-vertix, end-vertix for every trail of the whole path
    temp_vertix = c(temp_vertix[1], rep(temp_vertix[-c(1, length(temp_vertix))], each = 2), temp_vertix[length(temp_vertix)])
    temp_vertix = matrix(temp_vertix, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
  } else
  {
    temp_vertix = matrix(temp_vertix, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
  }

  # filter those rows from the data.frame that match the start and stop vertix
  temp_edges = apply(temp_vertix, 1, function(f) temp_graph_df %>% filter(from == f[1], to == f[2]))

  return(temp_edges)
}

lapply(l, my_get_edges, example_graph)

lapply(l2, my_get_edges, example_graph)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you work it out?

Comment: Hi emilBeBri. No, i sticked with the solution in the post and since the project didn't get continued back then, i never thought about improving the function afterwards :(

Comment: allright :) what I needed was simpler than what you have there, so I figured it out by using shortest_paths(), which cointains the list-element   x$vpath[[1]], which you can feed to the path=argument of E(). This makes it possible to select whatever paths you want and create attributes along the edges. Took some time working out though, the igraph syntax isn't very newbie-friendly